# How to use a regex test if a string contains an HTML page

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a script which makes submits a POST request via cURL to an external site and expects to receive a file in response. However on an error the site will return an HTML error page instead of the expected file.

I have the response stored in a string and I would like to check if the string contains an HTML page, if not, we can assume the string contains the requested file data.

I am having trouble creating a regex to test if the string is an HTML page. I would like to test the following:

- The data has a leading opening HTML tag: `<\s*html.*>`
- The data has a subsequent opening body tag: `<\s*body.*>`
- The data has a subsequent closing body tag: `<\/\s*body.*>`
- The data has a subsequent closing HTML tag: `<\/\s*html.*>`

I tried the following:

```
function isHTMLPage($data) {
  $html_file_regex = '/<\s*html.*>.*<\s*body.*>.*<\/\s*body.*>.*.<\/\s*html.*>/';
  return preg_match($html_file_regex, strtolower($data)) === 1;
}
```

The function returns false (fails to match) on the following test data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>test Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with my regex?

`/<\s*html.*>.*<\s*body.*>.*<\/\s*body.*>.*.<\/\s*html.*>/`

Comment: this may be simpler than you think; what does the `Content-Type` header return (between the different results)? e.g. if the service normally returns json you should see `application/json`, but the error page would switch to `text/html`.

Comment: i'm not sure of your purpose but don't parse the html use the HTML DOM Parser

Comment: It's standard to get back an html page on html failure, e.g. a 404 page. That will STILL be a valid html page, but it'll just say some version of "File not found". You should be checking the http status code instead.

Comment: You guys are correct, I should be looking at the return headers for errors, not the returned data.

Comment: Additional note: The above expression: `/<\s*html.*>.*<\s*body.*>.*<\/\s*body.*>.*.<\/\s*html.*>/` is a classic example of [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) - i.e. How NOT to write a regex; it may match an HTML file quickly, but it will take nearly _forever_ to declare a non-match on a non-HTML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` does not match newlines, unless you use the "dotall" modifier: `s`

That said, you shouldn't be doing this. What you *should* do instead is check for a status code, such as `404` to indicate that the file wasn't found. After all, what if the file you are expecting to get is an HTML file itself?

Comment: Though status codes aren't _always_ reliable. Though the person who served the content _should_ follow the standard, a lot of them categorize an error response as a `200 OK` and just server a failure page.

Comment: @BradChristie: I've never seen an error page with a 200 error code.  It makes me sad that people would do that :/

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Never said I endorsed it, just I've seen it happen. And I agree, it is sad. I've witnessed `/contact/1/` -> `200 OK` -> `{id:1,name:'foo'}` then followed up with `/contact/-1` -> `200 OK` -> `{error:'not found'}`.

Comment: It depends on the API really. My AJAX system always returns `200 OK` to say that the request itself was successful, then return `{"ok":true,[more data here]}` or `{"ok":false,"error":"Something went wrong"}` depending on the actual result of the request.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: yup; and I've seen some "proxy" the code using `{status:200,response:{...}}` and `{status:404,response:{msg:"not found"}}` (but both yield `200 OK`).

Comment: +1: Answered the question ***and*** provided a better alternative. Thanks Niet!

Comment: Status code was not reliable *but* the response URL was reliably different if an error occurred so I have a working solution!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `s` (PCRE_DOTALL) modifier:

```
$html_file_regex = '/<\s*html.*>.*<\s*body.*>.*<\/\s*body.*>.*.<\/\s*html.*>/s';
```

According to the PHP manual, “If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded.”